# Cannot boot ubuntu 12.04, getting a black screen. I tried a few things, but I can't help myself

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, boot-repair, nomodeset

I am currently unable to boot my ubuntu and am currently writing on my dual-booted windows 8.1.

I'll quickly wrap-up what I did before.

- got ubuntu 13.04, played around a bit. Installed nvidia drivers, readonly-mounted an earlier SSD with Windows 8 on it
- after this I got a whitescreen and thought I'd better go with ubuntu 12.04
- can't boot it, getting a black screen.

What I already tried:

- reinstalling 12.04 (didn't change anything)
- running boot-repair (didn't change anything)
- running it with "nomodeset" in grumb vs. nvidia problems (didn't work, couldn't get any further)

So what I got now is the URL from boot-repair **[paste.ubuntu.com/6219606](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6219606)**
and I also managed to check out my ubuntu partition in windows (boot.log is empty but a "dmesg"-file has some information, but I don't know wheter how or if at all to share that).

Thanks for any attempt in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert with use of Grub but I think it is trying to tell you that you have some how used to large a petition on an extended partition. To tell you the truth I did not know that was possible. According to the post Grub has repaired that but needs a change in bios setting to boot properly.....

"Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (120GB) disk!
pastebinit  packages needed
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory"

If you know how to alter your settings in the BIOS then try that. If you are not sure then wait till you get an answer from some one with more experience with grub because you do not want to screw up your Bios settings...

Personally I use Easy BCD to dual boot with. I am not a fan of Windows software but I have never been able to learn the GRUB and GRUB2 bootloaders. Easy BCD seems to work fairly well for my use.

This link will take you to their site....   http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

It is a free download that you install through windows. It is fairly uncomplicated to install and you can also easyly uninstall it. At least you will know if it is a bootloader problem with Grub or not.

Wish I could be of more help but Video Drivers are not my forte....